# How to add additional text (or string) to a binding in xaml

Tags: c#, string, xaml, concatenation, binding-context

I have this:

```
<Label Text="{Binding Height}" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".9,.17,-1,-1" TextColor="White" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" FontSize="Medium"/>
```

Obviously {Binding Height} takes up the entire text.

The binding is currently a double, and needs to remain so, I just need to concat an 'm' at the end to represent meters.

I have tried {Binding Height} m and {Binding Height + m} but obviously xaml doesn't work the same way a regular string concatenation would work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `StringFormat`.
Like this:

```
Text="{Binding Height, StringFormat='{}{0}m'}"
```

**Edited for clarity:**

You can write anything you want after the `{0}` argument.

For example, the above will produce values like 25m, 10m etc.

You can write something like this if you like:

```
Text="{Binding Height, StringFormat='{}{0} is a good number.'}"
```

The above will produce, for example:

```
10 is a good number.
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thanks. How would I add spacing though? I tried simply adding a space between <...}m'> changing it to. <...} m'> but that didn't work... it still printed with no space.

Comment: Hi, I edited my answer. Let me know if that answers your question.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Maybe I just had to clean my program then. it didn't read the space. I did however do another line for weight and entered kg instead of m, and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `StringFormat`?

```
<Label Text="{Binding Height, StringFormat={0}m}"
```

Comment: Unfortunately this one left red squiggly lines under the text in the xaml page which wouldn't run